# A way to make multiple preg_replace clearer

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm trying to convert an inputed string to match ranges and here are the lines I've made so far :

```
$targets = "1-  6;20; 20-4,71100  12";
$ranges = preg_split("/[,;]/",    // Splits sthe string into an array on any comma , or semicolon ; encountered
    preg_replace("/[\s]/", "",   // Removes remaining white spaces
        preg_replace("/[^;][\s]+/", ";",  // Replaces all white spaces that are not preceded by a semicolon ; by a semicolon ;
            preg_replace("/[\s]*[-][\s]*/", "-", $targets)   // Replaces all dashes - surrounded by any number of white spaces by a single dash -
        )
    )
);
```

These lines work pretty well but I'd like to make it more beautiful...
Here is the output :

```
  array (size=5)
  0 => string '1-6' (length=3)
  1 => string '20' (length=2)
  2 => string '20-4' (length=4)
  3 => string '7110' (length=4)
  4 => string '12' (length=2)
```

The question is : is there any way to make it clearer ? (Such as binding results with the replacement in an array ?)
Could you give me some examples, I'm not very proud of these lines :/
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a code review question. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you post an example of the data before and after it's run through this? Your comments are helpful, but it would be easier if there was a test data set to try something neater against.

Comment: Hmm, not really, I'm not used to chain functions that way, I just don't know if there is other way to do it :V

Comment: Added data example and output

Comment: Why is `71100  12` split in two groups? There is no comma or semicolon¨

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^;][\s]+/", ";", $somevar)` considers thats any white space not preceded by a semicolon should be a semicolon

Comment: `preg_replace("/[^;][\s]+/", ";",  // Replaces all trailing spaces after a semicolon ;` is wrong. All trailing spaces after semi-colon can be removed with `preg_replace("/;\s+$/m", ";")` (if the text is multiline, else remove `m` at the end).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I misused the word trailing, I thought it meant "following a semicolon".

Comment: Then it must be `preg_replace("/;\s+/", ";",`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match ranges with whitespaces inside, and after you get an array with them, remove all kind of whitespaces.

To extract the ranges, the regex may look like

```
'~\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vBpmE8/1). The `\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?` will match 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of a `-` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces, and then 1+ digits.

In PHP:

```
$targets = "1-  6;20; 20-4,71100  12";
if (preg_match_all('~\d+(?:\s*-\s*\d+)?~', $targets, $m)) {
    print_r(preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $m[0]));
};
```

The `preg_replace('~\s+~', '', $m[0])` will remove all whitespace from the matches.

If you may have Unicode whitespace, add `u` modifier to the `preg_replace` call:

```
preg_replace('~\s+~u', '', $m[0])
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-6
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 20-4
    [3] => 71100
    [4] => 12
)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly and is far more clearer !

Comment: @Jleu BTW, you do not need to use the `preg_replace` if you know what whitespace chars you can have in your data. You may just list them in an array and pass it to `str_replace`: `str_replace(["\r","\n", "\t", " "], '', $m[0])`